# Angular 2 file structure for project

Tags: angular

Let say I have file structure like below in my project (taken from documentation):

```
-app
--core
--feature1
--feature2
--shared
```

So, where should I put something like:

```
- communicates.service (service to manage communicates (.message(), .error())
- communicates.component (component which is responsible for content of communicates on my page)
- authorization.service
- and for example feature1.service (feature2 uses this service)
- feature2.service
```

I am not sure if I should put it to core or shared.

Regards

Comment: I normally just created a "services" directory and stick them in there under the "app"

Answer (score 3):

Usually app-wide services should be kept in the `core` module. This way you'll be sure that they will be singletons and you won't have multiple instances of the same service running at the same time.

So

- I would keep most of the app-wide services in the `core` module
- All common presentational components, directives, pipes, modules in the `shared` module
- All section specific elements (eg. services, components...) in it's feature module

You should have a read here, it's very well explained:

- Shared modules: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules
- Core module: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#the-core-module
- Feature modules: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#feature-modules

Comment: Yes, I know it, but for example I have features: task and task-list. Task list should be "shared" for other features which can display task list. But also task-list can be as subfolder in task feature folder. How to solve this case?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite get your question... if both task and task-list are shared features, why don't you add them in the shared module?

Comment: task is not a shared feature. Task.component feature is a subpage but task-list.component may be used in other features.

Comment: So, as I understood: `task-list.component` is shared and it uses internally `task.component`. In this case I would put both of them in the `shared.module` but I'll just export only `task-list.component` since it's the only one used other features.

Comment: If some components use each other should they both be in shared?

Comment: Again, I did not get your question... What do you mean by "use each other"? If component A uses component B and they are both shared, put in shared module and export both, otherwise export only the shared one, as I said before. I think you may be over-complicating it. Is component A unique to feature A? If yes just put it in module A. If it's a app-wide service put it in core module, if it's presentational or a service which doesn't have to be singleton put it in shared module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147600/discussion-between-crash-and-michal-bialek).

Comment: Ok, so i am on chat

Answer (score 1):

It a bit depends on your project size, but I prefer structuring by use case. And stuff that is used site-wide will be in a shared or in a use-case specific folder. 
Looks like it makes sense to refactor the project a bit.

Maybe this helps you a bit, it is based on [mgechev/angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed), which is a great starting point for larger size projects:

```
./auth
./auth/store
./auth/store/actions
./auth/store/actions/action-creators
./auth/store/async-services
./auth/store/facades
./auth/store/reducers
./data-models
./data-models/classes
./data-models/interfaces
./data-models/types
./root-store
./root-store/async-services
./root-store/facades
./root-store/store
./shared
./shared/accordion
./shared/config
./shared/disclaimer
./shared/footer
./shared/helpers
./shared/loading-spinner
./shared/navbar
./shared/pipes
./storefront
./storefront/breadcrumbs
./storefront/error
./storefront/facets
./storefront/hero-banner
./storefront/product-catalog
./storefront/product-catalog/product-list
./storefront/product-catalog/product-list/product-card
./storefront/product-detail
./storefront/product-detail/aside
./storefront/product-detail/assets
./storefront/product-detail/features
./storefront/product-detail/header
./storefront/product-detail/media
./storefront/search
./storefront/store
./storefront/store/actions
./storefront/store/actions/action-creators
./storefront/store/async-services
./storefront/store/facades
./storefront/store/reducers
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you do any code restructuring or shifting of modules, just to give you quick thought about this, every folder structuring is done to make the development easy and help developers to easily locate the modules.

so the feature related declaration need to go in feature folder itself and something which you makes out as common need to go in the shared folder with different folders in it

```
-app
--feature1
---feature1.module
---feature1.service
---feature1.model
--feature2
---feature2.module
---feature2.service
---feature2.model
--shared
---communicates
----communicates.service
----communicates.component
```

Comment: Yes, I know it, but for example I have features: task and task-list. Task list should be "shared" for other features which can display task list. But also task-list can be as subfolder in task feature folder. How to solve this case?

Comment: not sure you expressed this correclty, but as per your comment you have already said that task-list need to be shared for other features, so this in any case need to go into shared folder

Comment: task.component in features uses task-list.component and task-editor.component. I have similar model also for other features, for example suites.component with suites-list.component and suites-editor.component. suites-editor.component may use task.list.component. There are many similar dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2+ Style Guide is a work in progress. For example, you can take the following scenario like describe in this [repository](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app).

```
-app
--components
---components.module.ts
---feature1
---communicate
----communicate.component.|html|css|spec.ts|ts
--guards
--models
--pipes
--services
---feature1.service.ts
---feature2.service.ts
---communicate.service.ts
---authorization.service.ts
```